# How do i make a div stick down from his div container?

Tags: html, css

So i have Three Divs. One container and two inside. The thing i want to do is kind of a sticky footer.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>   
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background:green;
}

.one{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background:blue;
}

.two{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
}
```

I know it maybe a rookie question, but im here to learn and i didnt find an answer.
Here is a JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/oz0amshe/
If someone can tell me how do i make to **.two** stay down of **.container** i will be very happy.
Thank you all for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your needs, it may be enough to simply position the `div` absolutely in relation to the container. So for example:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.two {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Here your adjusted ***[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oz0amshe/1/)***.

Comment: Just what i was looking for it even worked better with what i am doing. Thank you my friend. Really apreciated.

Comment: I will mark your question in 6 minutes because it wont let me.

Comment: Also take a loot at http://ryanfait.com/html5-sticky-footer/ if you want a true sticky footer that is a little more robust.